# Study is the set of polynomial functions is closed or open in $(C[-1,1], \|\cdot\|_\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I think that this set cannot be open, however I don't know how to proof that it is closed. Could someone help me please?.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Look up the Weierstrass approximation theorem.

Comment: "Not open" is not the same thing as "closed" - a set can be both open and closed or neither open nor closed. (This set is neither)

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ be the set of polynomials in $C[-1,1]$.

Then $A$ is not closed because of the sequential characterization of closedness.

We can find a sequence of polynomials which converges to a function $f$ which is not a polynomial because $A$ is dense in $(C[-1,1],||.||_{\infty})$

Also is not open because its complement,namely $A^c$, is not closed.

Again from sequential characterization of closedness,take the sequence $f_n \in A^c$ such that $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n(x+2)} \to^{||.||_{\infty}}0 \notin A^c$

Answer (score 1):

The polynomials are not closed in $C[-1,1]$ with the max-norm, because it is well known that they are dense in it, and not every continuous function is a polynomial.

Comment: This does not really answer how to prove it. Seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Ok thanks , but how can we proof that polynomials are dense un C[-1,1]?

Comment: @mathlife -- This is a standard fact, and clearly you are not expected to prove it in an exercise such as you posted here. Anyway, there are at least two ways to see why the polynomials are dense in $C[-1,1]$, one is called Bernstein's theorem, and actually constructs a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to a given continuous function in $[-1,1]$. The other is the Stone-Weirstrass theorem. Look them up.

Answer (score 0):

It is known that $(C[-1,1], \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is a Banach space.

If the space of polynomials $\mathcal{P}[-1,1]$ were a closed subset of $C[-1,1]$, then $(\mathcal{P}[-1,1], \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ would also be a Banach space.

The countable set $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots \}$ is a Hamel basis for $\mathcal{P}[-1,1]$.

However, infinite-dimensional Banach spaces necessarily have uncountable Hamel bases, as you can see [here](http://planetmath.org/banachspacesofinfinitedimensiondonothaveacountablehamelbasis).

This is a contradiction, hence $\mathcal{P}[-1,1]$ cannot be closed.

$\mathcal{P}[-1,1]$ also cannot be open in $C[-1,1]$, since it is a proper subspace of $C[-1,1]$. If it were open, then there would exist an open ball $B(0,r) \subseteq \mathcal{P}[-1,1]$ around $0$. For any $f \in C[-1,1]$ we would have:

$$\frac{f}{\|f\|}\cdot \frac{r}{2} \in B(0,r) \subseteq \mathcal{P}[-1,1] \implies f = \frac{2\|f\|}{r} \cdot \left(\frac{f}{\|f\|}\cdot \frac{r}{2}\right) \in \mathcal{P}[-1,1]$$

since $\mathcal{P}[-1,1]$ is closed under scalar multiplication. This is a contradiction with the fact $\mathcal{P}[-1,1] \ne C[-1,1]$.

Comment: No need to mention Hamel bases.

Comment: @uniquesolution Of course, there is an elementary argument using the Weierstrass approximation theorem, like the one you used. I just wanted to give another way to see it.